# Google Maps Android Studio Capa Encima

Tags: android, google-maps

Quiero saber de que forma o cómo se puede poner una capa sobre el mapa para colocar información, algo como esto:

[image: Abrir la segunda capa cuando realice alguna acción en el mapa]

Comment: La tira azul con el nombre y reseña? o el pin sobre el lugar?

Comment: La tira azul como si fuese abrir otra actividad!

Comment: El panel en azul lo puedes crear con el nuevo elemento BottomSheet aquí un tutorial: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/bottom-sheets-en-android/

Comment: Muchas Gracias lo estoy mirando y es lo que necesito Gracias

Comment: El panel en azul lo puedes crear con el nuevo elemento BottomSheet aquí un tutorial: sgoliver.net/blog/bottom-sheets-en-android